# Ajax doesn't work when I change document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code which I found at W3Schools and when I use `document.getElementById` it works, when I change this to `document.getElementsByClassName` (on my full code, I will have more than `<p class="txthint">` why I thought I should be using `documents.getElementsByClassName`) it just stops working.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/PSCRM.asp" -->
<%
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_cmd
Dim Recordset1_numRows

Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PSCRM_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT prodref FROM dba.proditem where created >= '2015-08-01' and obsolete = '0' ORDER BY prodref asc" 
Recordset1_cmd.Prepared = true

Set Recordset1 = Recordset1_cmd.Execute
Recordset1_numRows = 0
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="">
<input type="text" onChange="showCustomer(this.value)" value="">
</form>

<br>
<div class="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
  var xhttp;    
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?prodref="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<%
Recordset1.Close()
Set Recordset1 = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: getElement`s`ByClassName returns an array of elements,  whereas `getElementById` only returns one element. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint")[0]` instead to get around this.

Comment: you need to be on chrome, safari, IE9 +   or firefox 3+   for this feature to work, that and the array as mentioned [index].   On a side note, have not seen an asp page for ages :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I really should move up from ASP.

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one of the same ID in a page for the reasons you're encountering. This is why it's good practise to use classes, especially if you need to append any divs at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName), you'll notice that you are returning an array of object whereas [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)  returns a single element.

With the array, there is no prototype for innerHtml, this is only exposed on a single element.

What you will need to do is iterate through the list of elements you retrieve from the getElementsByClassName.

```
var elements =document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
 elements[i].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText
};
```

Try that and see if it helps

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of nodes, not a single node.  You need to iterate that collection and set the `innerHTML` property on each node:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint");
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
    nodes[i].innerHTML = '';
```

Your current code is setting the property on the collection itself which, as it's perfectly valid JavaScript, doesn't error, but causes nothing to update either - it's just now the node collection has an unused `innerHTML` property.